# Can't ping from/to trunked VLAN

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan

So I have configurable switch, two pc (1st PC is on VLAN 101, 2nd PC is on VLAN 102) and a router that is on VLAN 103.

VLAN 103 (named as router) is in trunk mode.

```
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allow vlan 102,103
```

VLAN 101(pirmas) VLAN 102(antras) is in access mode

```
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 101 / vlan 102
```

But still I can't ping from VLAN 103 to VLAN101 102 and vica versa, even if its trunked. Here is is the scheme:

[image]

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is doing your inter-VLAN routing? If you send a packet from machine 1 tagged with VLAN 101, but your other machines are tagged with VLAN 102 & 103 respectively, how do you expect the VLANs to talk to each other, each is a unique network. http://www.technig.com/configure-inter-vlan-routing-cisco-router/

Comment: You're using Cisco's product. Cisco's Knowledge Base article on VLANs and trunking already covers everything you need to know about configuring VLANs, trunk ports, and inter-VLAN routing.

Answer (score 0):

On the router, you need to configure the VLANs as subinterfaces:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 no shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.101
 encapsulation dot1Q 101
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.102
 encapsulation dot1Q 102
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
!
```

PCs on VLAN 101 need an address in the `192.168.1.0/24` network with a gateway of `192.168.1.1`.

PCs on VLAN 102 need an address in the `192.168.2.0/24` network with a gateway of `192.168.2.1`.

The router doesn't need a separate VLAN. You could ser up a management VLAN if you want, but you don't have any devices in that VLAN.